# How do I force a task on airflow to fail?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a python callable `process_csv_entries` that processes csv file entries. I want my task to complete successfully only if all entries were processed successfully. Task should fail otherwise

```
def process_csv_entries(csv_file):
    # Boolean 
    file_completely_parsed = <call_to_module_to_parse_csv>
    return not file_completely_parsed

CSV_FILE=<Sets path to csv file>
t1 = PythonOperator(dag=dag,
                      task_id='parse_csv_completely',
                      python_operator=process_csv_entries,
                      op_args=[CSV_FILE])
```

t1 seems to complete successfully irrespective of returned value.
How do I force PythonOperator task to fail?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

raise exception when you meet the error condition ( in your case: when file is not sucesfully parsed)

```
raise ValueError('File not parsed completely/correctly')
```

raise relevant error type with suitable message

Comment: This works..Thanks! I was hoping there would be a better way to handle this.

Comment: This will not force the task instance status to "failed" though... Is there a way to bypass the retries config?

Answer (score 50):

Yes, raise `AirflowException`, this will cause the task to move immediately to failure state.

`from airflow import AirflowException`

`ValueError` can be used for fail and retry.

Comment: Any exception fails the task and moves it to failure state.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent airflow from retrying the task if retries are set? For example, there are some errors that you don't want/need to retry, such as invalid input related errors.

Comment: @JoeJ, there is a PR open for that: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7133

Comment: AirflowException also avoids printing the stack trace on the logs +1

Answer (score 30):

if you want to fail the task without retries use `AirflowFailException` :-

Example :-

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
def task_to_fail():
    raise AirflowFailException("Our api key is bad!")
```

If you are looking for retries use `AirflowException` :-

Example:-

```
from airflow import AirflowException
def task_to_fail():
    raise AirflowException("Error msj")
```

Answer (score 26):

[`AirflowFailException`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/exceptions/index.html#airflow.exceptions.AirflowFailException) is now available in [Airflow 1.10.11](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7133) to make the task **fail without retries**

Comment: For those of you wondering what version "now" means, it was [introduced in 1.10.11](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/changelog.html#airflow-1-10-11-2020-07-10)